# How to add enters and use a custom font in a JLabel?

Tags: java, html, fonts, jlabel, enter

Recently, I have attempted to create a textbox that uses a custom font. The problem I had with it though, is that it also requires certain enters in several places. At first, I tried using \n or \r\n, but that didn't work. This lead me to using HTML, but this gave me the problem of my font not loading in. I tried to fix this using several methods, including change the style of the HTML body, like this:

```
<html><body style="font-family: pixelmix">Text</body></html>
```

The font in question, pixelmix is an imported font, not installed on the PC. It is, however, known to the program and can be used without HTML. I don't know if HTML can work with uninstalled fonts, but if anyone had any idea on how to get enters AND a custom font, please let me know.

Comment: set font via ˋJLabel.setFont(...)ˋ, apply newlines with ˋ<br />ˋ tag. Note, however, that ˋJLabelˋ is not designed for multiline text; you will achieve much better results  with a ˋJTextAreaˋ. If you insist on html with styling in your component, try ˋJTextPaneˋ.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of using a JTextArea, that did it. Only thing is now that the JTextArea enlarges itself when the text goes outside its boundaries. This does not cause an issue for me, but I was just wondering what I could do to stop this from happening.

Comment: Use `JTextArea.setLineWrap(true)` to wrap long texts.